# Add column as factor to data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

My data.frame `d` looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1LJn.jpg

If I execute the following:`d <- d %>%
  mutate(reporter=ifelse(value_ex>0, report_ctry, partner_ctry))`

The newly created variable does not contain "DE" and "FR", but 10 and 16. Obviously, the problem is that variable is numeric not a factor. What's the easiest way to tell R that the newly created variable is supposed to be a factor and not numeric?

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  We cannot cut and paste that to work with your example.  Instead,  use `dput(d)` to create a text format of your data that we can just paste into R. if your data is too big for that,  you can use `dput(head(d, 15))`

Comment: can you provide str(d) as well? My guess is that `report_ctry` and `partner_ctry` are factors and ifelse is returning the levels instead of the character values "DE" and "FR"

Answer (score 1):

As @Jonathan Hill mentioned, the conditional formatting return the levels instead of the character value. Inserting `as.character` for `report_ctry` and `partner_ctry` will return back the character value.

```
df %>% mutate(reporter=ifelse(value_ex>0, as.character(report_ctry), as.character(partner_ctry)))
head(df2)

  report_ctry partner_ctry value_ex reporter
1          DE           FR 30.26170       DE
2          DE           FR 20.01426       DE
3          DE           FR 33.28977       DE
4          DE           FR 38.37996       DE
5          DE           FR  0.00000       FR
6          DE           FR 19.72538       DE
```

Data frame was generated as follow:

```
df <- data.frame(report_ctry=c(rep("DE", 10), rep("FR", 10)),
                 partner_ctry = c(rep("FR",10), rep("DE", 10)),
                 value_ex = runif(20, min=0, max=50))

df$value_ex[5] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` in base R does not preserve type in many circumstances. Use `if_else` from dplyr which has more restrictions but works in most situations. Used data made by @Adam Quek

```
d <- df %>%
    mutate(reporter=if_else(value_ex>0, report_ctry, partner_ctry))
```